# Perform JavaScript function from Folium popup with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, folium

I am trying to call a JavaScript function (created in a `<script>` tag in the HTML file)...

```
function myFunction() {
   divelement.style.display = "block";
}
```

...from a link in a Folium popup created in the routes.py Flask file.

```
folium.Popup("<a href='#' onlick='myFunction();'>Click here</a>")
```

However, when I click on the link in the popup, the function cannot be found.

Could you help? Thanks in advance.